# How to write a query to get the value for a specific key in "project_branch_config" field?

Tags: mongodb

I have the following record in a collection ,I am trying to write a query to get the value for a specific key in "project_branch_config" field,my query `db.getCollection('build_configs').find({"project_branch_config":"ACIWiFiDriver"})` doesn't yield anything?any guidance on how to fix this?

Also,should I structure my record differently (instead of a list of dictionaries) for this use-case?

Following is one record in my collection

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d7fd4a33e398ff0cca87fe2"),
    "train" : "trainB",
    "project_branch_config" : [ 
        {
            "ACItechDriver" : "trainB"
        }, 
        {
            "techCapture" : "trainB "
        }
    ]
}
```

MY QUERY

```
db.getCollection('build_configs').find({"project_branch_config":"ACIWiFiDriver"})
```

CURRENT OUTPUT:-

Fetched 0 record(s) in 3ms

```
EXPECTED OUTPUT:-

        {
            "ACItechDriver" : "trainB"
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

In your question, I can you're querying for 'ACIWiFiDriver' but the expected OP is 'ACItechDriver'. I assume it is a typo

To check if the field exists use the below query:

```
db.build_configs.find({"project_branch_config.ACItechDriver": {$exists: true}}, {_id: 0, "project_branch_config.ACItechDriver": 1} )
```

To check if the field has specific value use the below query:

```
db.subdoc.find({"project_branch_config.ACItechDriver": "trainB"}, {_id: 0, "project_branch_config.ACItechDriver": 1} )
```